# Android - How to set more than 2 items in action bar on landscape mode

Tags: android, split, android-actionbar, landscape-portrait

I'm trying to set action bar for my app.
I want that the action bar will contain 4 icons.
in portrait mode it work fine!
the items are at the bottom of the screen.
I'm using the following code :

```
 android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
```

This code succesfully split the Action bar in portrait mode..

when the orientation is on landscape mode , only 2 icons display in the upper screen  and the rest of the icons are in the menu icon button  (the 3 little dots )
what should i do to make the other icons spread all over the action bar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your menu.xml place android:showAsAction="always" or "ifRoom" under each item

Comment: I had the problem in both landscape and portrait when using "ifRoom", where only 2 of 4 icons were showing.  Changing it to "always" fixed things so all 4 appear in actionBar - thanks!